# Solve Basic partial differential equation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Help me solve the partial differential equation.

$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2} - 3\frac{\partial^2 z }{\partial x \partial y} = e^{2x-y} + e^{x+y} + \cos(x + 2y)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish you put more effort in..as it's nice question. But can I help you with a hint..$$x^2+2y^2-3xy = (x-2y)(x-y)$$
Where $x$ and $y$ are not the variables you see on the rhs of your equations.